# gedit: Replace only mouse-selected text

Tags: gedit

I'd like to add characters between my manually mouse-selected word in the text file. The reason behind this is to create Anki (flashcard application) cards quickly.

I take notes in a text file in the form of questions and answers.

What I'm trying to do is replace `ORIGINAL_SELECTED_TEXT` to `{{c1:ORIGINAL_SELECTED_TEXT}}`

**NOTE**: The template that I want to replace is fixed, which is `{{c1:"TEXT"}}`

For example:

**From:**

```
Q: Who and when invented light bulb?
A: Thomas Edison in 1879
```

**To**

```
Q: Who and when invented light bulb?
A: {{c1:Thomas Edison}} in {{c1:1879}}
```

**Here's what I've got so far**

I've tried using gedit External Tools and wrote this in **Edit** section:

- Input=selection
- Replace={{c1:}} (I don't know what I should write to make gedit use the selected text as a variable)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The External Tools plugin is for running an external command. To use that for this, you'll need to provide a command that will take the selected text and convert it to what you want in the output, and then have gedit use that output.

A number of possible commands can be used. For example:

- `sed 's/.*/{{c1:&}}/'`
- `printf '{{c1:'; cat; printf '}}'`
- `printf '{{c1:%s}}' "$GEDIT_SELECTED_TEXT"`

The first might not work well with multi-line selections, the latter two should wrap the whole selection even if it spans multiple lines.

Then set the options accordingly:

- Input: Current selection
- Output: Replace current selection

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It works perfectly. I use your 3rd commands because it's simple and easy to manipulate.